# Funciones asincronas API NodeJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo una duda de si estoy realizando bien un recorrido para una APi en NodeJS. Les cuento como es mi recorrido.
Primero entra en un archivo de rutas donde tengo

```
app.get('/producto', function(req, res) {
    getProducts(req, res);
})
```

Este archivo requiere:

```
const { getProducts } = require('../services/productService');
```

Ese **productService** va a:

```
let getProducts = (req, res) => {
 //codigo aca
}
```

Antes tenia todo el código del servicio dentro de **app.get**, pero quiero separarlo para que sea mas claro. Como lo realice sigue siendo una funcion asincrona? Como estoy entrando en Javascript y NodeJS hace poco me pierdo si esta bien como estoy realizando los callback o si es necesario agregarle el async.

Gracias.

Comment: Ahí no estás usando ninguna *callback*, solo son llamadas a funciones de toda la vida. Por lo demás, si tienes `getProduct` exportado en `module.exports`, **debería** funcionar.

Comment: Pero en la funcion en app.get no es un callback el segundo parametro? Y como haria para que fuera asincrona getProducts?

Comment: Ah, cierto. Esa no la he contado :-)

Comment: Esa función es llamada desde una que **si** es asíncrona (el `get`), por lo tanto es asíncrona desde el punto de vista del código global, pero síncrona desde el punto de vista de tu función de respuesta al `get( )`.

Comment: Debería hacerla asincrona a la funcion getProducts? O con tener asincrono el get ya estaria bien?

Comment: Las cosas asíncronas tienen sus peculiaridades. Entre ellas, que usan *closures* que hay que mantener en memoria durante todo el tiempo necesario. **Personalmente** (ojito, es una opinión) tal y como la tienes está perfecta.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @Trauma!

Comment: Si tu método `getProducts()` recibe los parámetros `req, res`, también podrías usarlo directamente como la función middleware que espera `app.get()`. Claro, si es que no necesitas hacer nada previemente con `req` o con `res`. Por ejemplo: `app.get('/producto', getProducts);`. Saludos

Comment: Tenia pensado realizar de esa manera pero para las validaciones, es decir hacer algo como `app.get('/producto', { validarRequest, validarToken }, function ...; ` Que opinas de esto? @MauricioContreras

Comment: Si `validarRequest` y `validarToken` son también middlewares, debes pasarlos como tal, no como propiedades de un objeto. En todo caso la forma correcta sería: `app.get('/producto', validarRequest, validarToken, getProducto);`. Y debes asegurarte que tanto `validarRequest` como `validarToken` llamen a `next()`. Por lo tanto deben recibir 3 argumentos, por ejemplo: `validarRequest = (req, res, next) =>  { ... }`. Saludos

Comment: Claro, ya hago eso solo que me confundi y lo llamo asi: 
`app.get('/usuario/:id', [verificarToken, verificarAdminRole], function(req, res){ //codigo }`